# copying mongo database to local

Tags: mongodb

I need to copy a mongo database from my Mongo Cloud Atlas and use it with my meteor app locally, but after doing the following steps, `db.users.find().count()` still reports the "older" database count not the new one I thought I correctly restored after mongodump. Any ideas?

dump from the Atlas cluster, run from the app parent directory:
`mongodump --host Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username myname --password myPswd --authenticationDatabase admin --db dbName`

Terminal reports lines like:

`2018-03-17T05:03:57.462+1100    writing dbName.tempLinksGroupsCol to 
2018-03-17T05:03:57.465+1100    done dumping dbName.commonCol (1 document)`

Confirm the presence of a dump directory which contains a directory "dbName".

copy data from newly dumped dbName to my local dbName by running this command from the app parent directory:

`mongorestore --maintainInsertionOrder -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 --drop -d dbName dump/dbName`

I get lines like:

`2018-03-17T05:21:48.826+1100    finished restoring dbName.cronHistory (0 documents)
2018-03-17T05:21:48.826+1100    done`

switch to the app directory and run the command:
`meteor`
open a new terminal and run the command:
`meteor mongo`

issue the command from the mongo shell:
`db.users.find().count()`

Still reports the old count not the new one from the restored database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 --drop
```

I see that you are not providing correct path of dump. just mention path of dump folder.

See documentation for mongorestore https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/

Comment: I get: don't know what to do with subdirectory "dump/dbName", skipping...
2018-03-17T06:36:21.416+1100 done

Comment: as I mentioned, ignore it. it's for internal use. Try above command and let me know if it worked

Comment: `mongorestore --maintainInsertionOrder -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 --drop -d dbName dump/` still did not get the updated records.

Comment: `mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 --drop -db dbName dump/` gives "too many positional arguments"

Comment: I have updated my answer. please see. you'll need to run this command from parent folder of `dump` folder. It will restore database with same name as you exported.